# Template matching two 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, template-matching

I have an 3D numpy array, `start_array`, I do some processing to it by applying some random translations and rotations to get `transform_arry`. I have access to both the arrays only. I want to identify the random transforms done to the arrays. What would be a quick and easy way to do it using python?

Comment: Could you share some examples, maybe?

Comment: You can find the translation by calculating the center of the points in each case and compare them, for rotation, you can do SVD. Also, always post questions according to [mcve]